# Backup Homescreen shortcuts

Tags: backup, home-screen-shortcuts

I have a Galaxy S5. Last time I updated the OS, all my homescreen shortcuts and widgets were deleted and restored to the factory default, and it took an hour or 2 to set everything back the way it was.

Now Android is harassing me with another update, and I don't want to go through that process again.

Is there an easy/cheap way to backup my shortcuts and widgets before updating again? All the backup apps I've seen recommended cost money, have a bunch of features I don't need, and might not work with my Android version (I have Android 4.4.2).

Comment: Luckily when updating to Android 5 it saved my shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do it  (++) with Helium or My backup which are available on Google Play,  they both have a free version and a premium version , if you've updated to Android 5.0 like me your probably out of luck because the home screen has been locked down in "Lollipop" I did however get my wallpaper back by using Samsung Smart Switch but not short cuts though 
 (++ I don't know for sure  if it can be done in 4.4.2 "Kitkatt" because I never got a chance to try it )

Good luck , Sonny .